# How to generate dynamic variable names in pandas dataframe

Tags: python

I have one variable in python (value may change)

```
a = 6
```

Now depending upon the values I have to generate 6 clusters from `K-means clustering` 
which gives me following labels in array

```
y_km
Out[36]: array([2, 5, 5, 2, 5, 0, 0, 1, 1, 4, 3, 4, 1, 0, 2, 2])

cluster_0 = np.where(y_km == 0)
cluster_1 = np.where(y_km == 1)
cluster_2 = np.where(y_km == 2)
cluster_3 = np.where(y_km == 3)
cluster_4 = np.where(y_km == 4)
cluster_5 = np.where(y_km == 5)
```

Then I store the location of every labels in an array to different variables. I want to automate this process so that I don't have to explicitly write code for variable names (`cluster_0,cluster_1,cluster_2...)`

```
for i in range(a):
    cluster_'%d'%i = np.where(y_km == i)
```

I am doing above but this gives me syntax error.
Then I am defining one column in a dataframe `tsp_data_unique`

```
tsp_data_unique['Clusters'] = 'Null'
```

Then I am doing following to assign corresponding cluster labels in dataframe.

```
tsp_data_unique['Clusters'].iloc[cluster_0] = 'Cluster 1'
tsp_data_unique['Clusters'].iloc[cluster_1] = 'Cluster 2'
tsp_data_unique['Clusters'].iloc[cluster_2] = 'Cluster 3'
tsp_data_unique['Clusters'].iloc[cluster_3] = 'Cluster 4'
tsp_data_unique['Clusters'].iloc[cluster_4] = 'Cluster 5'
tsp_data_unique['Clusters'].iloc[cluster_5] = 'Cluster 6'
```

Can I automate the above process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is generally better practice to just use a `dict()` and, then make your 'dynamic variable names' keys to the dictionary instead. You could use:

```
clusters = {}
for i in range(a):
    clusters['cluster_{}'.format(i)] = np.where(y_km == i)
```

You can then access the values in the dictionary using eg `clusters['cluster_1']`.

Comment: can I generate `Cluster 1,Cluster 2...` strings dynamically depending upon value of variable `a`

Comment: I am doing like this.. `tsp_data_unique['Clusters'].iloc['cluster_{}'.format(i)] = 'Cluster {}'.format(i+1)` but its gives me an `ValueError: Can only index by location with a [integer, integer slice (START point is INCLUDED, END point is EXCLUDED), listlike of integers, boolean array]`

Comment: `tsp_data_unique['Clusters'].iloc` is a function, not a dictionary. You can't access it via a key

Comment: Is it possible to achieve what I wanted?

Comment: I am doing this.. `tsp_data_unique['Clusters'].iloc[clusters['cluster_{}'.format(i)]] = 'Cluster {}'.format(i+1)` But its assigning only `Cluster 6` value in a dataframe others are entered Null.

Answer (score 2):

I want to suggest you to store your *clusters* in a dictionary:
And the code will be like:

```
clusters = dict()
for i in range(a):
    clusters[i] = np.where(y_km == i)
```